# Why does my animation look completely different when rendering?

Tags: blender

I have created an animation of a robot which when running does the animation the way I like it to. When I render it, certain objects like the arm of the object does not show. Any reason as to why this is?

Comment: Questions like that are off-topic for StackOverflow. Please refere here: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

show/hide_render icon:
[image]

Check if this little (Show/hide_render) icon is turned off for that specific mesh.